# Why no. of limit affect Postgresql handling select query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, database-performance

I have a table named `user_profiles` with more then 24M rows now. I need to retrieve all data and index them into Elasticsearch.

I wrote a program to consume and transform data so that they are indexible into ES. I select data from DB using `.Rows()` in xorm so that memory will not blown up. It used to be working really fine.

I was trying to reindex all documents again but I found the data loading speed from DB is much slower. In the past when I run the select all query with order by it returns the first row almost immediately but not now.

I inspected the explain statement and found if I select documents with LIMIT of 13.05M it will use the index that matches my order by of the query but not for 13.06M beyond.

The last time I indexed documents I remember it is arround ~10M

With `LIMIT 13050000`

```
- Plan: 
    Node Type: "Limit"
    Parallel Aware: false
    Startup Cost: 0.56
    Total Cost: 30928006.04
    Plan Rows: 13050000
    Plan Width: 592
    Plans: 
      - Node Type: "Index Scan"
        Parent Relationship: "Outer"
        Parallel Aware: false
        Scan Direction: "Forward"
        Index Name: "user_profiles_pkey"
        Relation Name: "user_profiles"
        Alias: "user_profiles"
        Startup Cost: 0.56
        Total Cost: 56959518.12
        Plan Rows: 24033936
        Plan Width: 592
```

With `LIMIT 13060000`:

```
- Plan: 
    Node Type: "Limit"
    Parallel Aware: false
    Startup Cost: 30605613.02
    Total Cost: 30638284.91
    Plan Rows: 13060000
    Plan Width: 592
    Plans: 
      - Node Type: "Sort"
        Parent Relationship: "Outer"
        Parallel Aware: false
        Startup Cost: 30605613.02
        Total Cost: 30665697.86
        Plan Rows: 24033936
        Plan Width: 592
        Sort Key: 
          - "user_id"
          - "system_name"
        Plans: 
          - Node Type: "Seq Scan"
            Parent Relationship: "Outer"
            Parallel Aware: false
            Relation Name: "user_profiles"
            Alias: "user_profiles"
            Startup Cost: 0.00
            Total Cost: 2357864.36
            Plan Rows: 24033936
            Plan Width: 592
```

I see there is a huge Read and Write IOPS in AWS RDS monitor tool. I think DB is trying to recreate the sorting and disregard the fact that primary index can be used directly. What can I do?

Here is the EXPLAIN query:

```
EXPLAIN ( FORMAT YAML )
SELECT *
FROM "user_profiles"
ORDER BY "user_id", "system_name"
LIMIT 13050000;
```

Here is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE user_profiles
(
    user_id     UUID        NOT NULL,
    system_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    key_values  TEXT        NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT user_profiles_pk PRIMARY KEY (user_id, system_name)
);
```

Comment: what happens after you vaccuum & analyze?

Comment: Nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Index scan is a random read and it is generally more expensive than sequential read. But it hardly depends on your storage device. For example for HDD it is something about 10x times slower. Postgres planner uses expected [page read costs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS) to choose what is better. By increasing limit you hit the border when seqscan is expected to be more effective.

please consider making several queries instead of fetching 13M records at once.